# ASP.NET MVC 3 - disable 100 http

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

When I'm send to server 'multipart/form-data' request, ASP.NET return 100 HTTP (continue). I'm want disable this behavior. How do this?

Answer (score 0):

In App.Config, add

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```